# Observer API memory usage

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, webapi

there is an example on the MDN document.

```
function createObserver() {
  let observer;

  let options = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: buildThresholdList()
  };

  observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersect, options);
  observer.observe(boxElement);
}
```

I am wondering when is the `observer` object would be free by the GC.

Because there is no variable access to `observer` after function is end.But this example still functional.

Can memory usage be seem in chrome dev-tool ?

Thank for any help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can see chrome memory usage in the "memory" tab...

As for when it is GC. It will be collected only once it is destroyed. It is because the callback could have side-effects.